# spark sql databricks - transaction log error after optimize

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have two tables, written like this:

```
f_em.write.format('delta').mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('rens.f_em')
f_dial.write.format('delta').mode("overwrite").saveAsTable('rens.f_dial')
```

These tables work fine. I can query them. However, they are large (ca. 11 billion rows), so to enhance performance, I want to optimize them.

```
%sql
optimize rens.f_em
zorder by (RKNR)
```

and

```
%sql
optimize rens.f_dial
zorder by (rknr)
```

I have no clue how optimize exactly works and what zorder by exactly does. I used the optimize function before on another table, and just used the attribute I use the most for linking/joining in the zorder by statement. This enhanced performed significantly so I tried the same approach here.

After running the optimize statement, I cannot query from the tables any longer:

For one of the tables I receive this error after a simple select statement

```
You are trying to read from `dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/rens.db/f_em` using Databricks Delta, but there is no
transaction log present. Check the upstream job to make sure that it is writing
using format("delta") and that you are trying to read from the table base path.

To disable this check, SET spark.databricks.delta.formatCheck.enabled=false
To learn more about Delta, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/delta/index
;
```

and other error:

```
Error in SQL statement: FileNotFoundException: dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/rens.db/f_dial/_delta_log/00000000000000000000.json: Unable to reconstruct state at version 2 as the transaction log has been truncated due to manual deletion or the log retention policy (delta.logRetentionDuration=30 days) and checkpoint retention policy (delta.checkpointRetentionDuration=2 days)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: Check the filename for the new query. It looks for the data in the path

```
dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/rens.db/f_em
```

But most likely you saved the table to:

```
dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/rens.f_em .
```

This might be due to your dot-notation in you `saveAsTable(rens.f_em)`.

In the SQL query, the dot is interpreted by the SQL API as a database, not as a delta table called `rens.f_em`.

EDIT: Given your reply, I would like to propose such a workaround, which I personally always use and favor due to robustness.

```
table_dir = "/path/to/table"
f_em.write.format('delta').mode("overwrite").save(f"{table_dir} + /rens.f_em")

spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE rens")
spark.sql(f"CREATE rens.f_em USING DELTA delta.`{table_dir}/f_em`")

spark.sql(f"OPTIMIZE delta.`{table_dir}/f_em` zorder by (RKNR)")
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me. The dot in the saveAsTable is used to denote database rens, with table name f_em. This worked as expected: After the saveAsTable statement, there was a table f_em in my database, which I could query from. The optimize statement messed this up though

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. Sounds like a strange error.

I usually use this workflow, maybe it helps:

1. save Delta Table with write.format("delta").save("path")
2. Register a database in HIVE metastore and register the table to it by using the desired path
3. Do OPTIMIZE on the delta table by giving the path

This works quite robust and is just one or two lines of more code.